# How To Implement FFMPEG LL-HLS

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

How is Low Latency HLS achieved with FFMPEG? From my understanding thus far, I am seeing changes around the `-f` option. For example:

```
-f dash -method PUT http://example.com/live/manifest.mpd
```

But there isn't much information researching on LL-HLS with ffmpeg. Making smaller segments I am finding comes at the cost of choppiness in the stream. Has anyone done this? And is the protocol actually adopted or just in "theory".

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of aspects with low-latency streaming in general. A good overview of the existing technologies you can find in this talk:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Col12gjnNlI

With respect to low latency HLS (LL-HLS) & ffmpeg as a source: LL-HLS needs smart origin (manifest manipulation feature for partial updates) and H2 push functionality, which is not implemented in ffmpeg. So, there is no support for LL-HLS in ffmpeg.

Best regards,
Marc